# Tensorflow CNN plot learning rate vs accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to implement the Cyclic LR approach (for finding the optimal learning rate boundaries), which requires me to plot the learning rate vs accuracy. But right now, I can't seem to get that working. When training the model, part of the code below, it either plots an empty graph, or gives me empty lists, and I'm not sure if I am misunderstanding something in the TF language.

A little elaboration on the code ([credits](https://kwotsin.github.io/tech/2017/02/11/transfer-learning.html)), a bit above this code, I have created `acc_list = []` and `lr_list = []`. These two lists should be filled with values, with every global step the model does. So I want to append these values to the list, and when the model is finished, plot these two lists in a graph, to find learning rate boundaries. 
Do I have to do more 'tf-coding'? Right now I thought running `sess` is enough, as this also gives the `current learning rate` and `current accuracy`, thus the values are present.

```
def run():
#Run the managed session
    with sv.managed_session() as sess:
        for step in range(num_steps_per_epoch * num_epochs):
            #At the start of every epoch, show the vital information:
            if step % num_batches_per_epoch == 0:
                logging.info('Epoch %s/%s', step/num_batches_per_epoch + 1, num_epochs)
                learning_rate_value, accuracy_value = sess.run([lr1, accuracy])
                logging.info('Current Learning Rate: %s', learning_rate_value)
                logging.info('Current Streaming Accuracy: %s', accuracy_value)


            #Log the summaries every 10 steps.
            if step % 10 == 0:
                loss, _ = train_step(sess, train_op, sv.global_step)
                summaries = sess.run(my_summary_op)
                sv.summary_computed(sess, summaries)
                iteration_step += 1

            #Run training if not 10 steps
            else:
                loss, _ = train_step(sess, train_op, sv.global_step)
                iteration_step += 1


            lr_list.append(sess.run([lr1]))
            acc_list.append(sess.run([accuracy]))

        #We log the final training loss and accuracy
        logging.info('Final Loss: %s', loss)
        logging.info('Final Accuracy: %s', sess.run(accuracy))

        plt.plot(lr_list, acc_list)

        #Once all the training has been done, save the log files and checkpoint model
        logging.info('Finished training! Saving model to disk now.')

        sv.saver.save(sess, sv.save_path, global_step = sv.global_step)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing TF specific here. `lr_list.append(sess.run([lr1]))` will indeed append the current value of `lr1` tensor to `lr_list`. It is pure Python at this point. If the list is empty at the end, debug it like you would any regular python code... e.g. make sure this line is actually reached as many times as you expect, make sure that no one else is mutating the list between the time you added something to it and you plotting its values.

Comment: Managed to solve it indeed! Had to look very carefully where and when I applied sess.run, and how to make sure the values were kept stored and accessible later on :)